# Implicit conversion sequences?

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion

[N3797](http://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3797.pdf) §13.3.3.1 [over.best.ics] defines an implicit conversion sequence concept. More precisely, it says:

> An implicit conversion sequence is a sequence of conversions used to
>   convert an argument in a function call to the type of the
>   corresponding parameter of the function being called. 
>   The sequence of conversions is an implicit conversion as defined in
>   *Clause 4*, which means it is governed by the rules for initialization
>   of an object or reference by a single expression (8.5, 8.5.3).

The thing is `Clause 4` doesn't concerned in user-defined conversions and ellipsis conversions, it only defines standard conversion. Since, the sentence ***The sequence of conversions is an implicit conversion as defined in Clause 4*** isn't clear to me. How can the rules from the clause 4 ever be applied to all three conversion sequences. I mean

> A well-formed implicit conversion sequence is one of the following
>   forms:
>
> — a standard conversion sequence (13.3.3.1.1),
>
> — a user-defined conversion sequence (13.3.3.1.2), or
>
> — an ellipsis conversion sequence (13.3.3.1.3).

Comment: Can you reference the source of your specification literature?

Comment: @self, it says [N3797](http://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3797.pdf).

Comment: @chris Perhaps, I wasn't being precise enough for you. I seemed to have thought that I implied that a link could, perhaps, be provided.

Comment: @self [Where do I find the current C or C++ standard documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81656/where-do-i-find-the-current-c-or-c-standard-documents) Although I like chris' link a lot better.